# Fatal error in the page rendering

Tags: magento-enterprise, image, error

I'm getting this error on a Magento EE products listing page, Magento stops rendering HTML.

```
<ul class="products-grid">
<li class="item first">
<a href="http://magentoee.local/shopper-blu" title="Shopper-blu" class="product-image">
<img src=" <-- FROM THIS POINT MAGENTO STOPS RENDERING HMTL
```

It seems that Magento goes on a Fatal Error when it try to render Product Image Url.

By Excluding Writing Permission errors i've modified every file permission to 777 (i'm in Dev Env !! )

```
 chmod -R [doocument_root] 777
```

Nothing change , so i think that this is not a permission error.

Where can i fing additional information about this error ?

**SOLVED**

It was a GD Librar issue. It wasn't installed on my server.

Comment: check your theme folder catalog/product/view/media.phtml file and check image tag code.

Comment: Please check the debug guide and report back: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/5